# django cron_tab is not sending email why?

Tags: python, django, cron

I am trying to play around `django cron_tab`, I also know there's one called `django cron` but `cron_tab` is recommended by lots people instead.

I have it installed (I believe it is installed properly as when I run commands there are no errors)

But it is not working though. (Does it have to do with running it locally that's why it's not working?)

I have followed all the steps here to install `cron_tab`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-crontab

I did install it via pip, I put the it into `INSTALLED_APPS`

also added in my settings

```
CRONJOBS = [
('1 * * * *', 'main.extras.cron_job.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

I have a folder named `main` under it is `extras` directory and under `extras` directory I have a file named `cron_job.py`

## cron_job.py

```
def my_scheduled_job():
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    print('######################################')  // this is added because I want to see if terminal / console would print this out as I would know at least the function did at least run but never seen this got printed

    send_mail(
        'cron job test',
        'Here is the message.',
        'from@hello.com',  // using real email locally
        ['to@hello.com'],  // using real email locally 
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

I believe the setting for my cron is run the following function every minute

I am currently using `pycharm` and running the whole application using `python manage.py runserver` which is running properly.

then I ran this command as the documentation mentions.

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

then I would get this message

```
adding cronjob: (1d3207c6e306b905406569c4fab310a3) -> ('1 * * * *', 'main.extras.cron_job.my_scheduled_job')
```

if I run this command

```
python manage.py crontab show
```

I would get this message

```
Currently active jobs in crontab:
1d3207c6e306b905406569c4fab310a3 -> ('1 * * * *', 'main.extras.cron_job.my_scheduled_job')
```

Can someone please give me a hand of where I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I also tried this too, which didn't work though

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'main.extras.cron_job.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is wrong:

```
CRONJOBS = [
('1 * * * *', 'main.extras.cron_job.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

I'm not a cron expert, but I think it will run like 00:01, 01:01, 02:01 (every hour)... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview)

For testing purposes, try to use:

```
CRONJOBS = [
('* * * * *', 'main.extras.cron_job.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

It will execute your script every minute, or:

```
CRONJOBS = [
('*/5 * * * *', 'main.extras.cron_job.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

to run it each 5 minutes (look the "/": */1 - every 1 minute, */2 - every 2 minutes ...)

Comment: sryz, I should have edited.  I tried */1 too...I will update my code